# Find the product of all entries of vector x

Tags: matlab

Here is what I am trying to do:

Let `x` be a vector with n entries `x1,x2,...xn`. Write a mat-lab program which computes the vector p with entries defined by

```
pk = X1*X2....Xk-1*Xk+1...Xn. 
for each k =1,2,...n.
```

`pk` is the product of all the entries of `x` except `xk`. (use prod command of compute the product of all the entries, then divide by `xk`). Take the appropriate special action if either one of more the entries of x is zero. Using vectors throughout and no 'for' loop.

I spent too much time to figure out this problem. I still could not get it. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Brute force:

   ```
   n = numel(x);
   X = repmat(x(:),1,n); %// put vector in column form and repeat
   X(1:n+1:end) = 1; %// make diagonal 1
   result = prod(X); %// product of each column
   ```
2. Saving computations:

   ```
   ind = find(x==0);
   if numel(ind)>1 %// result is all zeros
       result = zeros(size(x));
   elseif numel(ind)==1 %// result is all zeros except at one entry
       result = zeros(size(x));
       result(ind) = prod(nonzeros(x));
   else %// compute product of all elements and divide by each element
       result = prod(x)./x;
   end
   ```